# Why do dictionaries in Python check for a key-existing during assignment?

Tags: python, dictionary, variable-assignment, order-of-execution

So I heard that `dict` instances in Python will check if a key already exists before assigning a value. This seems very redundant to me, and I will explain why with an example.
**EXAMPLE:**

```
if(key in dictionary):
   dictionary[key] = dictionary[key] + 1
else:
   dictionary[key] = 1
```

So you can see in this example that, there would be no need to check if a key already exists for `dictionary[key] = dictionary[key] + 1`. Because the `dictionary[key]` in the right hand side of the assignment (`dictionary[key] + 1`) will retrieve the key if it is present, or raise a `KeyError` if the key does not already exist in the `dict` instance (note that the check to see if the key is present on the right hand side is not related to assignment). Whether a key already existed or not in the check on the left hand side (`dictionary[key] =`), will do nothing to the outcome. If no check was done, and you just calculated the hash-value for the `key` and assigned it that `value`. It would not matter if the key existed previously or not.
**ALSO NOTE:** That with or without the `if(key in dictionary):` a redundant check will be performed.

For the second portion of the example `dictionary[key] = 1`. The presence of a key or not in the check from `dictionary[key]` does not change the outcome, whatever value was at that previous `key` (if it was present) will just be overwritten by the `1`. So what is the point of the check before the set.

Maybe there is a reason for the implicit check during ASSIGNMENT before the set. It seems that there is a seperate check performed if the check is for a `dict` instance on the left or right hand side of the assignment. Because a missing `key` does not throw a `KeyError` on the left hand side, a new `key` is just made instead. I can't see an example of the need for the check prior to a set, but if you do! I would love to hear.

Comment: "heard"? Heard where? What evidence do you have that this is actually true?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because to be on-topic, a Stack Overflow question needs to be about a narrow, specific problem you actually face. Concerns that a language-level design decision may be suboptimal is not a problem you face, unless you can show that your program is behaving incorrectly because of it in some testable way.

Comment: BTW, the actual implementation of `dict` lives in https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/12a30bc1aa0586308bf3fe12c915bcc5e54a032f/Objects/dictobject.c#L240.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ill keep that in mind, about the proper creation of the dictionary! But wherever I heard it, does not matter. If there is not "implicit" check under the hood before the set for a `dict` instance during assignment, could you tell me so? If you know there is not, it would answer my question perfectly!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy YES! Thank you for the implementation of `dict`, I was looking for it but couldnt find it. I'll look through this now!

Comment: Look in particular for `PyDict_SetItem`.

Comment: Anyhow -- as I read it, there _is_ a check, but it's a necessary, integral part of the assignment to determine if we're replacing something else, to properly evict whatever we're replacing from memory (or at least decrement its reference count) and reuse the slot rather than allocating a new one if a preexisting storage location already exists. As such, it arguably is _an essential part of_ the assignment, not something done _before starting_ the assignment.

Comment: ("wherever I heard it, does not matter" -- I disagree, because a rumor or misapprehension does not an "actual problem that you face" make -- quoting from https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `collections.defaultdict(int)` or a `collections.Counter` would be more usual than the lambda. Please try to refrain from answering the question directly in the comments :)

Comment: @wim, ...it's improper to answer a question I think should be closed as off-topic. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you for the help, your explanation was nice. I also, on second thought, agree with you that where I heard it does matter. But I was afraid that explaining that would count as off topic. But it worked out in the end!

Comment: Yes, I agree it's improper to answer a question that you think should be closed as off-topic, regardless of whether you answer it in the comments or the answers. Personally, I think this question is quite fine.

Comment: Topicality rules are explicitly more lax in comments, though I'd need to spend time sifting through meta to back that up more than I think it's worth debating presently. Indeed, it's generally considered good form to provide a helpful response as a comment even while voting-to-close, when a helpful response is in fact possible.

Comment: `defaultdict()` first argument must be a  callable or None

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *is* actually true that Python will check whether a key is already existing in the dict when setting a new value. However, this check happens at the C level, not in Python code like shown in the question. The check is done by a helper function [`_Py_dict_lookup`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.12.0/Objects/dictobject.c#L1052) in CPython.

There are good reasons why the implementation must check if key is already existing:

- When replacing a key, the reference count for the old value must be decremented (no memory leaks)
- When replacing a key, [CPython guarantees a backing storage resize will not be triggered](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.12.0/Objects/dictobject.c#L1868-L1869) (user can modify an item during dict iteration).
- To distinguish "key exists" from "hash collision", an equality check may be necessary between new key and old key (collision handling)

When writing Python code, you don't need to do this kind of check. It would be more normal to use something like:

```
dictionary[key] = dictionary.get(key, 0) + 1
```

Or, if you're just counting keys, use a dict subclass such as [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead.

Comment: Also, Python needs to distinguish "key exists" from "hash collision".

Comment: @wim This is an incredible explanation! Thank you so much! It makes total sense now!

Comment: @user2357112 That's a great point, so it's not just in the memory-management details. I will add that to the reasons.

Comment: @wim Also I don't know if this is the proper place to say this, but if you can help it, please prevent this topic from being closed. I love having this so I can always return back to it when I need, and there are many great resources in the links you gave that I can use (Ill delete this comment if it is against some sort of guidelines). If the topic helps me, that should be a good enough reason to keep it open!

Comment: @ZenPyro Sorry, but I don't have that kind of authority. If two other users agree with Charles, it will be closed. A closure will not cause deletion, though, it just prevents new answers (i.e. you don't have to worry about this answer disappearing).